# Loading a Series into a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to load the time series returns for a few stocks into a DataFrame:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

#Get the historical prices
C= web.get_data_yahoo("C",start="2013-01-01", end="2018-09-24")
GS= web.get_data_yahoo("GS",start="2013-01-01", end="2018-09-24")


#Compute the returns
C_returns=C['Close'].pct_change()
GS_returns=GS['Close'].pct_change()

#Insert the returns into a pandas DataFrame:
df1=pd.DataFrame([C_returns,GS_returns],columns=['Citi','Goldman'])
```

The issue I'm having is that the resulting DataFrame contains empty series, although each of the returns series themselves have values. Am I loading the returns series into the DataFrame incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your series as a dictionary to [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Citi': C_returns, 'Goldman': GS_returns})
```

Or use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` and then assign column names.

```
df1 = pd.concat([C_returns,GS_returns], axis=1)
df1.columns = ['Citi', 'Goldman']
```

Or [`pd.DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) also works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([C_returns,GS_returns]).T
df1.columns = ['Citi', 'Goldman']
```